# How to declare a function pointer that returns a function pointer

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

How do you declare a function pointer that points to a function that has the same parameters and also returns a pointer to a function with the same parameters.

i.e.
`funcPtr` points to `func1(int a, int b)`, and `func1` returns a pointer to another function `func2(int a, int b)`. `func2` also returns a function pointer with the same signature as `func1`.

```
TYPE funcPtr = func1;
funcPtr = funcPtr(0, 1);
```

How does one declare `funcPtr`? What should `TYPE` be?

Comment: You can typedef.

Comment: Do you have a real use case? Or is it just an exercise. Either case, just use typedefs.

Comment: A function signature is the function as whole. It is therefore logically an impossible requirement to have "func1(int a, int b) returns a pointer to another function func2(int a, int b). func2 also returns a function pointer with the same signature as func1"

Comment: Ignoring the failing logic that makes the question impossible to answer, I suspect you are looking for something like `typedef void func_t (int, int);` and `func_t* func1 (int a, int b);`

Comment: Are you asking for some recursive (infinite) type X where `X == (*X)(int,int)` ?

Comment: @Ajay This is used in some legacy code I am trying to tidy up. It is for a state machine, where each state appears to be represented by a function that returns a pointer to another state function.

Comment: @SimonBagley If possible, replace the whole mess with `typedef struct state { int code; function task;  state* next; } state_t;`. There is no need to have a tight coupling between the state task and the next state.

Comment: To tidy-up your legacy code, instead of returning the function, return an enum and then call the function identified by the enum (e.g. use a table of functions). What the code did is no longer supported by modern compilers and modern architectures.

Comment: @SimonBagley See also [this question](http://c-faq.com/decl/recurfuncp.html) in the old [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Unresolvable self-reference

This is not possible directly. If you try to define a function pointer type where the function's return type is its own type, you will run into an unresolved self-reference, and that would require infinite recursion to resolve.

```
typedef funcType (*funcType)(void);
```

#### Return a `struct`

You can instead declare that the function return a structure, and the structure can contain a pointer to such a function.

```
struct func {
    struct func (*func) (void);
};

struct func foo (void);
struct func bar (void);

struct func foo (void) { return (struct func){ bar }; }
struct func bar (void) { return (struct func){ foo }; }

...
    struct func funcPtr = { foo };
    funcPtr = funcPtr.func();
```

#### Return a different function pointer type

If you prefer to stick to strictly pointers, you will need to resort to defining functions that return a different function pointer type. Thus, the result of the call would have to be cast back to the proper pointer type before being invoked.

```
typedef void (*funcPtrType)(void);
typedef funcPtrType funcType(void);

funcType foo;
funcType bar;

funcPtrType foo (void) { return (funcPtrType)bar; }
funcPtrType bar (void) { return (funcPtrType)foo; }

...
    funcType *p = foo;
    p = (funcType *)p();
```

#### Return an index<sup>†</sup>

You could instead define your functions to return an index to a table that represents the function that should be invoked.

```
enum funcEnum { fooEnum, barEnum };
typedef enum funcEnum (*funcType)(void);

enum funcEnum foo (void) { return barEnum; }
enum funcEnum bar (void) { return fooEnum; }

funcType funcTable[] = { [fooEnum] = foo, [barEnum] = bar };

...
    funcType p = funcTable[fooEnum];
    p = funcTable[p()];
```

†<sub>This was raised in comments and in [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50640762/315052), but presented here for completeness.</sub>

Comment: Why on earth would you ever need to use this in real-world programming though?

Comment: @Lundin: If functions represent states, a transition can be represented by returning the next state.

Comment: The sane thing to do would be to use an `enum` to represent the state, where the value gives an index in a function pointer lookup table. That is the industry standard way of writing finite state machines.

Comment: I have seen a lot of things used, that should never have passed code review. I remain convinced that this is nothing but obfuscation. There's a lot of people who like to use complicated design patterns just for the sake of showing off.

Comment: @Lundin: There is nothing particularly complicated here.

Comment: Except there's a tight coupling between a state and the next state, so that in order to know which state that is next, you need to know the current one. There is no rationale for why that coupling needs to exist in each state. There's many saner ways to implement that: arrays or linked lists.

Comment: Your original suggestion of using an `enum` with a function pointer lookup table does not ease that coupling, which as you say is industry standard. Anything fancier has the complexities of being fancier.

Comment: It does, as one item in the function pointer lookup table doesn't know which item that's next. And so such a table can be maintained and new states can be added, without actually touching any other code.

Comment: @Lundin: You are overthinking it. The complexity in a state machine is not how a particular transition is represented, but how to manage the decisions within the state that may branch to (perhaps many) different states as the next state. There is little difference between raising an event or returning a state directly in terms of the number of edges that have to be managed. Either way, you need a validator to determine that the state is making a valid transition. How the transition is coded doesn't really matter much.

Comment: I think the real problem in C is that you get an _infinite declaration_ as the function returns a function pointer and that function pointer needs to be typed to return a function pointer which needs to be typed to....

Comment: @jxh Embedding that logic inside the state is bad design. Properly designed state machines just return results from states and the state transition logic is located in one single place, not all over the place.

Comment: "This is not possible directly.", ya ???? this is completely false or I missing something

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Yes, a structure is allowed to refer to itself (but not contain itself).

Comment: @Stargateur: I guess I didn't define *directly*, but I did assume the OP didn't want to use a cast to invoke the function.

Comment: @Lundin: The existence of a state transition table does not adversely affect an implementation that consults such a table to decide which state function to return.

Comment: @Lundin You may not like it, and your counterarguments are well taken, but representing states as pointers to the functions that implement them *is* a popular and (in its way) elegant approach.  I suppose assembly language programmers are used to doing it this way.  People have been asking how to write "infinitely nested" function pointers forever; that's why [the question appears](http://c-faq.com/decl/recurfuncp.html) in the old [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).  (I could list some arguments against states-as-enums, too, but this isn't the place for it.)

Comment: @jxh It's mostly a matter of avoiding spaghetti programming. I've written more than enough FSMs to know that delegating the state transition logic to the individual states never ends well. And of cource a matter of loose coupling and OO - there is absolutely no reason why the "read_buttons" state needs to know about the "print_values" state.

Comment: @SteveSummit People have been writing crappily designed programs forever indeed. That doesn't mean that we should keep doing it. Most programmers are not even qualified enough to do a sound program design, so they pick up the first implementation idea that comes to mind. Then they rush off to some forum and ask how implement their idea. We can see the same programmer behavior with obscure things like recursion, variadic functions/macros, macros that create functions etc: in 95% of the cases it is the wrong solution to the original problem.

Comment: Apologies for the downvote; I had misread this answer. Converted to an upvote for good feelings (along with my thinking this is an excellent answer). And, for what it's worth, I have @Lundin down as a particularly wise contributor to this site.

Comment: @Lundin: My own experience is that for small state machines (which is most of them), the implementation style has little affect on the quality of the code. For larger state machines, more formal validation methods are required, which is why the transition table becomes important. As long as the state machine can be properly validated with automated testing and the code for any particular state machine is readable and understandable, it doesn't matter to me if the transition table is used directly by the state to return the next or if it is used by the state machine driver to derive the next.

Comment: @jxh The point is that the _decision_ which state to execute next should never be de-centralized, but kept at one single place in the program. If the state is reading the next state and returning it as part of some cumbersome API, then I suppose that's safe, but it's hardly good design.

Comment: @Lundin: From a different point of view, the designs are isomorphic, where one returns a transition table offset which maps to a function pointer, while the other returns a function pointer obtained from the transition table.

Answer (score 9):

This only an example without typedefs. You can try to change the parameters of the functions but the syntax is horrible and usually useless.

```
char (*(*((*foo)()))())()
```

foo is pointer to function returning pointer to function returning pointer to function returning char

Or you can use typedefs

for example

```
typedef int (*foo2)(int, int);

typedef foo2 (*foo1)(int, int);
typedef foo1 (*foo)(int, int);
```

or more general

```
typedef int (*foo`n`)(int, int);
typedef foo`n' (*foo'n-1`)(int, int);

...

typedef foo2 (*foo1)(int, int);
typedef foo1 (*foo)(int, int);
```

Comment: `(*(*((*foo)()))())()` somehow reminds me of [Brain-Flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79625/write-a-brain-flak-classic-interpreter/144386#144386) :-)

Comment: Your function pointer declaration at the start of your answer has a redundant pair of parentheses and could be simplified to `char (*(*(*foo)())())();`.  Also I think the idea of this question is that the function pointer type should be recursive and return a function pointer which returns the same type of function pointer which can be repeatedly called forever without eventually ending up with just a `char`.

Comment: nothing like recursive declarations exists in the C language. Only in the function body.

Comment: `(*(*((*foo)()))())()` looks like lisp :D

Answer (score 1):

I think the real problem in C is that you get an *infinite declaration* as the function returns a function pointer and that function pointer needs to be typed to return a function pointer which needs to be typed to....

The following are a few steps in such an infinite declaration, just to show how the declaration expands and expands:

```
int f0(int a) {
    return 1;
}
int (*f1(int a))(int) {
    return f0;
}
int (*(*f2(int a))(int))(int) {
    return f1;
}
```

---

As a solution for the legacy code, it can return a state number and a table with functions can be used to call the function defined for the state, for example:

```
#define STATE0 0
#define STATE1 1

int fx1(int a);
int fx2(int a);

int (*ftab[])(int) = {
    fx1,
    fx2
};

void examplefunc(void)
{
    int x = ftab[STATE1](3);  // example of calling function from table
}
```