# Call a function using a pointer and pass the pointer that can point to the function along in the parameters

Tags: c, pointers, parameter-passing, function-pointers

Say that I have a pointer to function `theFunc`. `theFunc` takes along a pointer that can point to any function with the same parameter list as `theFunc`, so the function called can set the passed pointer to NULL or a different function.

Using it would look like this:

```
while (funcPtr != NULL)
{
    funcPtr(&funcPtr);
}
```

Would defining this be impossible?

Comment: It's possible. For object pointers a void pointer `void *` is the generic pointer type. Any pointer to an object can be converted to a void pointer and back again. For function pointers, there is no pre-defined generic pointer, but nothing prevents you from inventing your own, e.g. `typedef void (*myGenericFuncPtr)(void);` Then it's just a matter of casting to/from the generic function pointer as needed.

Comment: Returning a pointer to a function, and passing an out parameter for a pointer to a function are fundamentally equivalent. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50638893/315052

Comment: What I want to do is [here](https://github.com/ADBeveridge/finite-state-machine/blob/main/finite-state-machine-possible.c). It does not work though, the complier cannot dereference a void pointer, and I do not know the proper cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's doable.

The simple way:

```
void (*fptr_t)(void*);
```

The function pointer is **data**, even though it point to non-data. Therefore a pointer to function pointer can be converted to `void*` without relying on compiler extensions.

This solution lacks type safety. However, it can be improved.

Currently, it is possible to declare a function taking unspecified number of parameters. It allows to form an incomplete function type. For example:

```
int foo();
```

declares a function that returns `int` and takes unspecified parameters. To have a function taking no parameters use `int foo(void)`.

This allows to declare a function taking a pointer to pointer to incomplete function type:

```
int foo(int (**)());

// call
int (*fptr)(int (**)()) = foo;
fptr(&fptr);
```

As mentioned in other answers `typedef`-ing function types makes the code cleaner.

```
typedef int foo_aux_f();
typedef int foo_f(foo_aux_f**);

foo_f *fptr = &foo;

fptr(&fptr);
```

It is possible to improve type safety by nesting the declaration of function types deeper and deeper.

```
typedef int foo_aux0_f();
typedef int foo_aux1_f(foo_aux0_f**);
typedef int foo_aux2_f(foo_aux1_f**);
typedef int foo_aux3_f(foo_aux2_f**);
typedef int foo_f(foo_aux3_f**);

foo_f fptr = &foo;
fptr(&fptr);
```

The perfect recursive type would be reached with infinite chain of declaration but in practice 2-3 levels are sufficient.

With some abuse of the syntax of `typedef` keyword it is possible to squeeze the declaration of this type:

```
typedef int foo_aux0_f(),
            foo_aux1_f(foo_aux0_f**),
            foo_aux2_f(foo_aux1_f**),
            foo_aux3_f(foo_aux2_f**),
            foo_f(foo_aux3_f**);
```

Unfortunately ... or fortunately, this trick will likely not work in upcoming C23 because the old function declarations without prototypes are planned to be removed from the language making `()` mean no arguments rather then unspecified number of argument.

Comment: _The perfect recursive type would be reached with infinite chain of declaration but in practice 2-3 levels are sufficient._ When I tried this I got bogged down by that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass pointer to pointer to function. The syntax is much easier if you use typedefs.

```
typedef  void somefunc(void);

void func1(void)
{
    printf("Func1\r");
}

void func2(void)
{
    printf("Func2\r");
}

void swapfunction(somefunc **ptr)
{
    if(*ptr == func1) *ptr = func2;
    else *ptr = func1;
}

int main(void)
{
    somefunc *ptr = NULL;

    swapfunction(&ptr);
    ptr();
    swapfunction(&ptr);
    ptr();
}
```

You can also use function return value:

```
typedef  void somefunc(void);

void func1(void)
{
    printf("Func1\r");
}

void func2(void)
{
    printf("Func2\r");
}

somefunc *swapfunction(somefunc *ptr)
{
    if(!ptr) return func1;
    else if (ptr == func1) return func2;
    else return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    somefunc *ptr = NULL;

    while(ptr = swapfunction(ptr))
    {
        ptr();
    }
}
```

Comment: But where you put in `ptr()` I want to do `ptr(&ptr);`

Comment: @ADBeveridge first snippet

Answer (score 1):

Ref your github comment, suggest you use a structure instead of type casting pointers to function pointers, etc. It's not exactly what you are requesting, but kind of.
The code will then look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct funcArgStruct 
{
    void (*state)(struct funcArgStruct *);
    // int extra_data; // optional
};
typedef struct funcArgStruct funcArg;

void start (funcArg *ptr);
void task1 (funcArg *ptr);
void stop (funcArg *ptr);

/* Implementation of an fsm. */
int main()
{
    funcArg ptr_, *ptr = &ptr_; 

    ptr->state = start;
    // ptr->extra_data = 0; // optional

    while (ptr->state != NULL)
    {
        ptr->state(ptr);
    }
    return 0;
}

void start (funcArg *ptr)
{
    ptr->state = task1;
}

void stop (funcArg *ptr)
{
    ptr->state = NULL;
}

void task1 (funcArg *ptr)
{
    ptr->state = stop;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void *a(void)
{
    printf("Calling a()\n");
    return NULL;
}

void *b(void)
{
    printf("Calling b()\n");
    return a;
}

void *c(void)
{
    printf("Calling c()\n");
    return b;
}

int main(void)
{
    void *(*funcPtr)(void) = &c;

    while (funcPtr) {
        funcPtr = funcPtr();
    }
}
```

I don't really see good uses, especially in passing the pointer to the function itself as an argument (which I why I omitted it) but whatever floats your boat. You can of course replace the arguments to whatever you need.

You could add a typedef to help out a bit with a type:

```
typedef void *(*myfunc)(void);
```

Then you could do the following:

```
myfunc funcPtr = &c;
// instead of: void *(*funcPtr)(void) = &c;
```

I don't think any of this is particularly elegant, but it should work.
Note that it doesn't matter if you assign `c` or `&c` to myfunc, or whether you return `a` or `&a` from one of the functions.

Comment: I would avoid `void *` as it might hide many potential issues